# is it possible to use custom load balancer for aws blue/green codedeploy?

Tags: aws-code-deploy

We are using custom load balancer to load balance udp traffic in our system. We were able to create a ASG group for the instances behind load balancer, but we are not able use blue/green codeDeploy to deploy the application. Is there a way we can customize codeDeploy to use the our custom load balancer to perform a blue/green deploy ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, CodeDeploy blue/green deployments do not support custom load balancer at this moment. It only supports Classic elastic load balancer.